# How to call a restricted firebase function with a service account key file?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup a restricted firebase function that can be called from another client application that runs outside GCP. So far I failed to setup the client application authentication to get passed the restricted access on the firebase funciton.

Here is what I did and tried:

- I created and deployed a simple helloWorld firebase function and verified that the function could be called from the client application with the default public access.
- I removed allUsers from the helloWorld permissions on GCP and verified that the function could no longer be called from the client application (I get "403 Forbidden" in the response).
- I created a new service account and added it as a member of "Cloud functions invoker" in the permissions panel of helloWorld on the GCP.
- I created a new private json key file for this service account.

Then I followed the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) to setup the client application authentication (see code below).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

async function main(){
  // get unix timestamp in seconds
  const current_time = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)

  // get the service account key file
  const service_account = require('./service_account.json');

  // create the jwt body
  const token_body = {
    "iss": service_account.client_email,
    "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
    "aud": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "exp": current_time + 3600,
    "iat": current_time
  }

  // sign the token with the private key
  const signed_token = jwt.sign(
    token_body, service_account.private_key, { algorithm: 'RS256' }
  )

  // get an access token from the authentication server
  const access_token = await fetch(
    'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    {
      method: 'POST',
      body: ''
      + 'grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer'
      + '&'
      + 'assertion=' + signed_token,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }
  ).then(res => res.json()).then(body => body.access_token)

  // call the firebase function with the Authorization header
  return fetch(
    url_hello_world, { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token } }
  ).then(res => res.text()).then(console.log)
}

main().catch(console.error)
```

Unfortunately when I run the previous code I get "401 Unauthorize" with the following header:

```
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token" error_description="The access token could not be verified"
```

After that I tried another approach with the following [tutorial](https://medium.com/google-cloud/easily-generate-google-signed-id-token-with-token-generator-d25b7e235f2e) (see code below).

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(require("child_process").exec)

async function main(){
  // activate a service account with a key file
  await exec('gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=' + key_file)

  // retrieve an access token for the activated service account
  const {stdout, stderr} = await exec("gcloud auth print-identity-token")

  // get the access token from stdout and remove the new line character at the
  // end of the string
  const access_token = stdout.slice(0,-1)

  // call the firebase function with the Authorization header
  const response = await fetch(
    url_hello_world,
    { headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token } }
  )

  // print the response
  console.log(await response.text())
}

main().catch(console.error)
```

When I run this code, I get the expected response "Hello World" so the previous code can call the firebase function with the service account permission.

However, the client application that I target cannot rely on the gcloud cli and I am stuck to the point where I tried to understand what does not work in the first version above and what I need to change to make it works.

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a Service Account `JSON` file, the following code can be helpful.

**package.json**

```json
{
    "name": "sample-call",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "googleapis": "^62.0.0",
        "node-fetch": "^2.6.1"
    }
}
```

**index.js**

```js
var { google } = require('googleapis')
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const fs = require('fs');
let privatekey = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('key.json'));
let url_hello_world = 'CLOUD_FUNCTION_URL';

let jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
    privatekey.client_email,
    null,
    privatekey.private_key,
    url_hello_world
)

async function main(){
    jwtClient.authorize( async function(err, _token) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return err
        } else {
            const response = await fetch(
                url_hello_world,
                {
                    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + _token.id_token }
                }
            )
            console.log(await response.text())
        }
    })
}
  
main().catch(console.error)
```

Comment: I tried with the code you provided but it did not work. I get "401 Unauthorized".

Comment: Not sure why, actually I deployed functions using the Firebase CLI and native GCP functions and in both cases the authentication worked. Also testing with `gcloud auth print-identity-token` or `gcloud auth print-access-token`. Could you please test with both commands in your code?